# Emails quarantine at client side from goanywhere mft

Tags: file, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses, transfer, managed

So our goanywhere mft is hosted up on aws ec2, and can be acces by client on xyz.com and my company name is abc(usefull when we talk about dns part).
Multiple aws services involved while setting it up, like ec2, sqs, route 53 & mainly ses.
So we have configured xyz.com domain, noreply_abc_mft@abc.com email , in verified entities in ses.

But recently whenever client requests for password reset. The email from noreply_abc_mft@abc.com is marked as potential spoof, and gets quarantine.

Any way to make it genuine email from mft?

suggestions are welcomed